# retrieve the oauth access code in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

```
$callbackUrl ="http://host/mgstore/customApi/test.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://host/mgstore/oauth /initiate?oauth_callback=".urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://host/mgstore/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://host/mgstore/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://host/mgstore/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'dfsfdsdf';
$consumerSecret = 'sdfsdfsdf';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
  $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
  $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
  $oauthClient->enableDebug();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    exit;
} else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];


    header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
    exit;
} else {
    $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
    $productData = json_encode(array(           
        'name'              => 'TEST PRODUCT',           
        'price'             => 11.11          
    ));       

$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products/337";
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData , 'PUT',  array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
$responseArr = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
print_r($responseArr);
}
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
  print_r($e);
}
```

the script redirect to the admin confirmation page,
how to get and use the access token without confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is how OAuth works: The Magento user has to grant your third party application access to their account.

If you don't want that, then don't use OAuth. Magento offers a regular API as well, that understands XML-RPC and SOAP: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html